# Var Type in PHP and if clause

Tags: php, if-statement

Look my php code:

```
// $_POST['dateToTimestamp'] LIKE '12.10.2015

$result = str_replace('.', '-', strtotime($_POST['dateToTimestamp']));
$result2 = date('d.m.Y', $result);

//$result like 1444600800
//$result2 like 1444600800
```

Now a if-comparisation

```
if($result == $result2)..
```

My Question is, why is the if-statement false (not equal)? The var-type is both the same, an "string".
The differents are use like var_dump.

Comment: Because the first result is: `string(10) "1444600800"` and the second `string(10) "12.10.2015"` Use `if($result == strtotime($result2))` and your if statement works as you want it

Answer (score 1):

Your two strings aren't the same at all.

See here: http://3v4l.org/G64Jq

Also, your `str_replace` is pointless, since `strtotime` returns an integer.

Just do this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($_POST['dateToTimestamp']);
$formatted = date('d.m.Y', $timestamp);
```

And then use those two different values however you need.